# Getting an Error parsing arguments for import sqoop

Tags: sqoop

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://PHCHBS-SD360117.eu.novartis.net:1533/NVS_DATAMART_IT" \
--username SYS_SIE \
--password SIEv \
--driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver \
--query 'SELECT GEO_NAME,SALES_AREA_CODE,SALES_FORCE_CODE,WEIGHT,SALES_AREA_NAME,REP_ID,REP_NAME,REP_ASGMNT_DATE,DISTRICT_ID,DISTRICT_NAME,DM_ID,DM_NAME,DM_ASGMNT_DATE,REGION_ID, REGION_NAME,RM_ID,RM_NAME, RM_ASGMNT_DATE,EXTRACTION_DATE,CYCLE  FROM NVS_DATAMART_IT.dbo.it_territory_hierarchy_bsp WHERE $CONDITIONS' \
-m 4 \
--hive-import \
--hive-database ph_com_r_ita_sales_integrator \ 
--create-hive-table it_dim_territory_hierarchy_bsp \
--target-dir "hdfs://sdata/ph/com/r/ph_com_r_ita_sales_integrator/abc"
```

I am getting below error while executing the above commands :-

> Warning:
>   /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/bin/../lib/sqoop/../accumulo
>   does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail. Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME
>   to the root of your Accumulo installation.
>
> 19/09/16 12:45:56 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version:
>   1.4.6-cdh5.11.2 19/09/16 12:45:56 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P
>   instead. 19/09/16 12:45:56 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing
>   arguments for import: 19/09/16 12:45:56 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool:
>   Unrecognized argument:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response Scott.
Issue is resolved by creating the table first in hive and then importing through Sqoop.
I am not sure why this parameter "--create-hive-table" isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

`--hive-database ph_com_r_ita_sales_integrator` could be the problem. I haven't found this argument in Sqoop documentation.

try using:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:sqlserver://PHCHBS-SD360117.eu.novartis.net:1533/NVS_DATAMART_IT \ 
--username SYS_SIE \ 
--password SIEv \ 
--driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver \ 
--query 'SELECT GEO_NAME,SALES_AREA_CODE,SALES_FORCE_CODE,WEIGHT,SALES_AREA_NAME,REP_ID,REP_NAME,REP_ASGMNT_DATE,DISTRICT_ID,DISTRICT_NAME,DM_ID,DM_NAME,DM_ASGMNT_DATE,REGION_ID, REGION_NAME,RM_ID,RM_NAME, RM_ASGMNT_DATE,EXTRACTION_DATE,CYCLE FROM NVS_DATAMART_IT.dbo.it_territory_hierarchy_bsp WHERE $CONDITIONS' \ 
-m 4 \ 
--hive-import --create-hive-table --hive-table ph_com_r_ita_sales_integrator.it_dim_territory_hierarchy_bsp \ 
--target-dir hdfs://sdata/ph/com/r/ph_com_r_ita_sales_integrator/abc
```